# unable to get rid of all emojis

Tags: python-3.x

I need help removing emojis. I looked at some other stackoverflow questions and this is what I am de but for some  reason my code doesn't get rid of all the emojis

```
d= {'alexveachfashion': 'Fashion Style * Haute Couture * Wearable Tech * VR\n⌚\nSoundCloud is Live @alexveach\nNew YouTube Episodes ▶️', 'andrewvng': 'Family | Fitness | Friends | Gym | Food', 'runvi.official': 'Accurate measurement via SMART insoles & real-time AI coaching. Improve your technique & BOOST your performance with every run.\nSoon on Kickstarter!', 'triing': 'Augmented Jewellery™️ • Montreal. Canada.', 'gedeanekenshima': 'Prof na Etec Albert Einstein, Mestranda em Automação e Controle de Processos, Engenheira de Controle e Automação, Técnica em Automação Industrial.', 'jetyourdaddy': '', 'lavonne_sun': '☄️ ✨\n°●°。Visual Narrative\nA creative heart with a poetic soul.\n————————————\nPARSONS —— Design & Technology', 'taysearch': 'All the World’s Information At Your Fingertips. (Literally) Est. 1991  #PrincessofSearch Sample  the Search Engine Here ', 'hijewellery': 'Fine 3D printed jewellery for tech lovers #3dprintedjewelry #wearabletech #jewellery', 'yhanchristian': 'Estudante de Engenharia, Maker e viciado em café.', 'femka': 'Fashion Futurist + Fashion Tech Lab Founder @technoirlab + Fashion Designer / Parsons & CSM Grad / Obsessed with #fashiontech #future #cryptocurrency', 'sinhbisen': 'Creator, TRiiNG, augmented jewellery label ⭕️ Transhumanist ⭕️ Corporeal cartographer ⭕️', 'stellawearables': '#StellaWearables ✉️Info@StellaWearables.com                  Premium Wearable Technology That Monitors Personal Health & Environments ☀️', 'ivoomi_india': 'We are the manufacturers of the most innovative technologies and user-friendly gadgets with a global presence.', 'bgutenschwager': "When it comes to life, it's all about the experience.\nGoogle Mapper \n360 Photographer \nBrand Rep @QuickTutor", 'storiesofdesign': 'Putting stories at the heart of brands and businesses | Cornwall and London  |  #storiesofdesign', 'trume.jp': '草創期から国産ウオッチの製造に取り組み、挑戦を続けてきたエプソンが世界に放つ新ブランド「TRUME」（トゥルーム）。目指すのは、最先端技術でアナログウオッチを極めるブランド。', 'themarinesss': "I didn't choose the blog life, the blog life chose me | Aspiring Children's Book Author | www.slayathomemum.com", 'ayowearable': 'The world’s first light-based wearable that helps you sleep better, beat jet lag and have more energy! #goAYO Get yours at:', 'wearyourowntechs': 'Bringing you the latest trends, Current Products and Reviews of Wearable Technology. Discover how they can enhance your Life and Lifestyle', 'roxfordwatches': 'The Roxford  |  The most stylish and customizable fitness smartwatch. Tracks your steps/calories/dist/sleep. Comes with FOUR bands, and a travel case!', 'playertek': "Track your entire performance - every training session, every match. \nBecause the best players don't hide.", '_kate_hartman_': '', 'hmsmc10': 'Health & Wellness \nBoston, MA \nSuffolk MPA ‘17  \n.\nJust Strong Ambassador \u200d♀️', 'gadgetxtreme': 'Dedicated to reviewing gadgets, technologies, internet products and breaking tech news. Follow us to see daily vblogs on all the disruptive tech..', 'freedom.journey.leader': 'MN\nWife • Homeschooling Mom to 5  • D Y I lover  • Small town living in MN.  \nAshleybp5@gmail.com \n#homeschool #bossmom #builder #momlife', 'arts_food_life': 'Life through my phone.', 'medgizmo': 'Wearable #tech: #health #healthcare #wellness #gadgets #apps. Images/links provided as information resource only; doesn’t mean we endorse referenced', 'sawearables': 'The home of wearable tech in South Africa!\n--> #WearableTech #WearableTechnology #FitnessTech       Find your wearable @', 'shop.mercury': 'Changing the way you charge.⚡️\nGet exclusive product discounts, and help us reach our goal below!', 'invisawear': 'PRE-ORDERS NOW AVAILABLE! Get yours 25% OFF here: #girlboss #wearabletech'}

for key in d:
    print("---with emojis----")
    print(d[key])
    print("---emojis removed----")
    x=''.join(c for c in d[key] if c <= '\uFFFF')
    print(x)
```

output example

```
---with emojis----
MN
Wife • Homeschooling Mom to 5  • D Y I lover  • Small town living in MN.  
Ashleybp5@gmail.com 
#homeschool #bossmom #builder #momlife
---emojis removed----
MN
Wife • Homeschooling Mom to 5  • D Y I lover  • Small town living in MN.  
Ashleybp5@gmail.com 
#homeschool #bossmom #builder #momlife
---with emojis----
Changing the way you charge.⚡️
Get exclusive product discounts, and help us reach our goal below!
---emojis removed----
Changing the way you charge.⚡️
Get exclusive product discounts, and help us reach our goal below!
```

Comment: Most characters above U+FFFF are not emojis and are 100% necessary for communication in most non-English languages.

Comment: (I’m also curious why you want to filter out emoji; what is the actual goal there? But either way, getting rid of all non-BMP characters is not the best way to do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical definition of what an "emoji" is. Various glyphs may be used to render printable characters, symbols, control characters and the like. What seems like an "emoji" to you may be part of normal script to others.

What you probably want to do is to look at the [Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) of each character and filter out various categories. While this does not solve the "emoji"-definition-problem per se, you get much better control over what you are actually doing without removing, for example, literally all characters of languages spoken by 2/3 of the planet.

Instead of filtering out certain categories, you may filter everything except the lower- and uppercase letters (and numbers). However, be aware that ꙭ is not "the googly eyes emoji" but the [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DOUBLE MONOCULAR O](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a66d/index.htm), which is a normal lowercase letter to millions of people.

For example:

```
import unicodedata

s = "Wife • Homeschooling Mom to 5  • D Y I lover  • Small town living in MN. "

# Just filter category "symbol"
t = ''.join(c for c in s if unicodedata.category(c) not in ('So', ))
print(t)
```

...results in

```
Wife • Homeschooling Mom to 5  • D Y I lover  • Small town living in MN.
```

This may not be emoji-free enough, yet the `•` is technically a form of punctuation. So filter this as well

```
# Filter symbols and punctuations. You may want 'Cc' as well,
# to get rid of control characters. Beware that newlines are a
# form of control-character.
t = ''.join(c for c in s if unicodedata.category(c) not in ('So', 'Po'))
print(t)
```

And you get

```
Wife  Homeschooling Mom to 5   D Y I lover   Small town living in MN
```